# InteliJ does not allow database connection

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm new to java and InteliJ. I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition) but it does not seem to have "Database" under "View" > "Tool Windows" :

[InteliJ_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSDJ.png)

Unfortunately I can not find the "Database Navigation" under the plugins :

[Pluigins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABCJ.png)

Comment: Maybe you need one of the paid versions?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce

Comment: or use eclipse for free

Comment: Notice the “Ultimate” colored tag in [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html). That means this is a premium feature available only in the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ. Ultimate edition is a commercial product requiring a fee.

Answer (score 4):

Is only available on the ultimate version. Community version does not have that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, I think plugins are not listing as marketplace has not loaded properly

Refer: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004275380-Marketplace-Plugins-are-not-loaded